# Why is there no space left on my new Intel Nuc on first boot?

Tags: system-installation, intel-nuc

I bought an Intel Nuc with a 4 GB ram and 500 GB hard disk. I am trying to install ubuntu on it following this tutorial:

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc

When I get to step 4.4), to run

> xzcat /media/ubuntu//ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz | sudo dd
>   of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=32M status=progress; sync

I get the following message

> error writing 'dev/mmcblk0 no spce left on device.

Do you know how could this happen and what should I do to solve it?

Comment: You should add the output of `sudo parted -l` to the question. I doubt a 500GB HDD is /dev/mmcblk0, so you night need to adjust according to your particular setup.

Comment: FYI - that tutorial is NOT for installing normal Ubuntu Desktop, it's for installing Snappy Ubuntu Core